# Adding Partition key to the existing collection- Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there any way that we can add Partition Keys for the Collections we already have in Azure-Cosmos DB, or we need to drop them and create new collections with partition keys and import the data from the previous collections?

I tried googling a lot and checking the settings of the collection but nothing helped. if you could that would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once created, a collections partition key definition cannot change. This means that you cannot add, remove or alter the partition key of a collection once created. 
You can use the Cosmos DB change feed to migrate to a new collection with the appropriate partition key.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I was looking for the steps and the code (Node JS) in google, but didn't find any. can you help me with the link.

Comment: I used DocumentDB Migration tool, to transfer documents and create new collection with Partition key.